# FortiClient VPN stuck at 48% with error code -7200 - Credential or SSL VPN connection issue

Tags: vpn, ssl

I've been facing an issue with my FortiClient VPN connection, and despite trying several troubleshooting steps, I'm still unable to resolve it. The problem is that the connection consistently gets stuck at 48%, and the error code I receive is -7200, indicating a Credential or SSL VPN connection problem.

Here are the steps I've taken to troubleshoot so far:

1. Enabled all TLS versions (except 1.1) and SSL in Internet Options.
2. Edited the VPN connection to ensure that all details are correct.
3. Added the SSL-VPN gateway URL (https://sslvpn_gateway:10443) to the Trusted sites.
4. Cleared the SSL state.

I am using Windows 11, FortiClient 7.2.2.0864

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. I'm reaching out to the community for any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this problem and how I can resolve it. Has anyone else experienced a similar FortiClient VPN issue, and if so, how did you manage to fix it?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: One rare issue: if time is out of sync by more than 10 minutes or so, SSL fails: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72866/what-role-does-clock-synchronization-play-in-ssl-communcation

Comment: You need to reach out to your System Administrator.